# On macOS Big Sur, how do I get the version of OpenSSL installed through Homebrew to be what is used on the command line?

Tags: command-line, openssl, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I’m on macOS Big Sur. I installed OpenSSL via Homebrew like this:

```
$ brew install openssl
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 40a7a0119 to f50b87031.
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 24 formulae.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 19 casks.

Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1l is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.1.1l, run:
  brew reinstall openssl@1.1
DIG139:cfs-web davea$ brew reinstall openssl
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1l
Already downloaded: /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7cb540b15662ae88caf307947df0254e5c64c04933630f7e9543cb018107ecbe--openssl@1.1-1.1.1l.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/blobs/sha256:ff8b2a965c680b4d9baccd60e799d0989e7dc562d2ba81696
Already downloaded: /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b6c57e7f9acfe19e13efdfa925e9d77bbc52f6965e0f48326f64f73d18ef9c81--openssl@1.1--1.1.1l.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling openssl@1.1 
==> Pouring openssl@1.1--1.1.1l.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Regenerating CA certificate bundle from keychain, this may take a while...
  /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l: 8,073 files, 18.5MB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k... (8,071 files, 18.5MB)
Removing: /Users/davea/Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl@1.1--1.1.1k... (5.4MB)
```

The above seems to imply I have already installed version 1.1.1, but when I check on the command line, I see the following:

```
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Where is this newer version of OpenSSL coming from and how can I make the versions consistent on my machine?

Comment: Note: the latest version of vanilla OpenSSL (i.e. not LibreSSL) is **3.0.2** as of writing this (read more [here](https://www.openssl.org/source/)). You can read useful installation info by executing `brew info openssl@3` (last two paragraphs before the "Analytics" section). So if you want this to be installed using Homebrew, you should execute `brew install openssl@3`.  Here is also an article covering the same question (though using the older version 1.1.1): [Installing OpenSSL library on macOS Catalina](https://yasar-yy.medium.com/installing-openssl-library-on-macos-catalina-6777a2e238a6).

Comment: The "newer" version (LibreSSL 2.8.3) actually comes with macOS out of the box (note that macOS switched to using [LibreSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreSSL) some time ago). I personally, not to interfere with the macOS default LibreSSL installation, just installed the latest `openssl@3` package and made an **alias** in my [`~/.zshrc`](https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac) file like this: `alias openssl3=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl`. This way I can use it separately by executing `openssl3` and leaving the default macOS OpenSSL version intact.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your shell so that your environment picks up brew version.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1/include"
```